# Can't edit in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I was using unity when in some moment i wasn't able to edit, i try to put in images, geometrical figures etc.
Also i can't scroll in my game window, i am new in Unity, so i don't know really well how to use it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIfAh.png)

I tried to change the properties > perspective to ortographic but I didn't
see any change...
I watched a bunch of unity tutorials thinking that it will help me to know what was my issue

Comment: you cant "scroll" game window because you set it to free aspect so it is the size of the chunk you see no more, no less. You also have nothing to see in your scene, and you edit in the scene so. please find a tutorial

Comment: You are looking at the `Game` tab, which is not where you edit from.  It is the view of the rendering camera.  Open the `Scene` tab, that is where you edit from.

Answer (score 1):

What you have opened is only the [Game View](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GameView.html). To edit your scene, you need to be in the [Scene View](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UsingTheSceneView.html).

If your Scene View is closed or not visible you can open it by navigating: `Window > General > Scene` or simply reset your layout by: `Window > Layouts > Reset all layouts`